# Disdainful pity...?

Tags: meaning, differences

My question stems from a conversation on *sympathy* and *pity*.

My girlfriend and I agreed that sympathy is feeling for someone, but without taking action or desiring to take action. *Pity*, then, overlaps with *sympathy* except there's a desire to take action to help the person in need. But *pity*, can also be more cynical, and it can demean, intentionally or otherwise, the person receiving pity.

So, this is where I'm curious, **is there a word that means specifically *disdainful or demeaning pity*?**

Comment: Pity is not the word for whatever you are describing. Pity is supposed to be a good thing. It is never disdainful or demeaning, which is a sick and insincere perversion of genuine pity. Rather, pity is *“The disposition to mercy or compassion; clemency, mercy, mildness, tenderness. [..] Tenderness and concern aroused by the suffering, distress, or misfortune of another, and prompting a desire for its relief; compassion, sympathy.”* I don’t really know a word for whatever kind of thing you are talking about, but it is not ***pity***.

Comment: Yeah, I know I'm not looking for pity. We already found that word. We're looking for a word that specifically means pity from an arrogant or demeaning place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you are actually looking for is (drumbeats) **pity**.

The word *pity*, of late, has become associated with being condescending. When you take pity on a person, you implicitly regard him as inferior and feckless. The words *sympathy* and *compassion*, on the other hand, do not have such negativity attached to them.

**References**:

- "Pity has the dynamic that the one to whom it is shown is considered not only in a worse situation than the one who shows pity, but also considered inferior." ([Newint](http://www.newint.org/features/2005/11/01/keynote/))
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pity)
- In English, people have started to avoid the word pity, because it has come to have associations of superiority. (See the note in [this link.](http://www.tlg.uci.edu/~opoudjis/lojbanbrochure/lessons/less1attitude.html))

Comment: Interestingly, [the definition of the term *pitiable*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pitiable) actually uses the OP's phrase: "2. Arousing disdainful pity."

Answer (score 1):

You could be looking for a word like ***contempt*** in the sense of 'looking-down' at someone (disdain, as you say).

Though this is not the same as 'pity', it is 'pity' itself that has acquired such connotations of disdain of late.