# Word for 'to feel superior by pitying others'

Tags: single-word-requests

**Example sentence:**
Some people like the fame and superiority gained by helping poor and posting that incident in social media.

Web search shows up pages like Why pity negative word, self-pity and not helpful.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67860/disdainful-pity

Comment: Your example sentence has nothing to do with *pity*. (It has more to do with self-aggrandizing.) Where does pity come into it?

Comment: For supposedly exalting others inferior to themselves, they themselves want to be exalted. Nietzsche.